# Custom name for an opencv image (complex name)

Tags: python, opencv, operating-system

hi I want to take a frame from the camera and save it in a folder 'images', I want the image to have name + current timestamp+.jpg , I'm getting error for typing it like this:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path2 , rn), img)
```

where `path2='images'`
and `rn=str(rightnow.strftime("%I:%M:%p"))`
i get this error : `could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'cv::imwrite_'`

how can I do it plz , I searched but didn't find an answer and I'm new to python, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is `os` specific.

**What happens if you run the code in Windows?**

Assume you have millions of code, are you going to change each slash `/` with `\`?

You should use `os.path.sep` instead of static slash declaration.

- First, remove the `:` in `strftime`, you can use `-` or `_` or nothing.

  - ```py
    rn = str(rightnow.strftime("%I%M%p"))
    ```
- Second, check whether the path exists, if it doesn't exist, create.

  - ```py
    path3 = "".join([path2, os.path.sep, rn])

    if not os.path.exists(path3):
        os.mkdir(path3)
    ```
- Third, create the image name

  - ```py
    save = "".join([path3, os.path.sep, "image_name.png"])
    ```
  - If you are executing the statement inside the loop, you may use counter

    - ```py
      counter += 1
      save = "".join([path3, os.path.sep, "image_name{}.png".format(counter)])
      ```

Code:

---

```py
import os
import cv2
from datetime import datetime

path2 = 'img2'
rightnow = datetime.now()
rn = str(rightnow.strftime("%I%M%p"))
img = cv2.imread("1.png")

path3 = "".join([path2, os.path.sep, rn])

if not os.path.exists(path3):
    os.mkdir(path3)

save = "".join([path3, os.path.sep, "image_name.png"])

cv2.imwrite(save, img)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path2 , rn), img)
```

to

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path2 , rn)+".jpg", img)
```